# In the figure form, adjust the whole size of “text” and “math” format at once (II): from \twocolumngrid to \onecolumngrid

Tags: math-mode, graphics, floats, horizontal-alignment, mathtools

This follows from a previous post [In the figure form, how to adjust the whole size of "text" and "math" format at once?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/467710/41144),

> In the figure form, how to adjust the whole size of "text" and "math" format "as a combined figure" at once, from the \twocolumngrid to \onecolumngrid? (say in the revtex)

My trouble is that in the "twocolumn" format of revtex4-1, if I use the following method @Herbert,

```
\documentclass[aps,prl,twocolumn,superscriptaddress,floatfix,letterpaper,nofootinbib]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb,varwidth}
\usepackage{showframe}


\begin{document}


\onecolumngrid
\begin{widetext}

\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering
\begin{center}
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{%
  \begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}
\begin{gather*}
 \overbrace{\underbrace{A \times B}_E\times
               \underbrace{C\times {D}}_{EFG}}^{\text{ABCDEFG}}\\[-\normalbaselineskip]
    \underbrace{\hphantom{A\times B\times C\times D}}_{\text{family}}
   \end{gather*}
  \end{varwidth}}
 \end{center}
  \caption{}
\end{figure}
\end{widetext}
\twocolumngrid

\end{document}
```

I got:

[image]

> This is not what I wanted. I want to have the figure stand in the middle, with adjustable size (likely 2/3 or 3/4 of the document width).
>
> However, the  "\begin{gather*}  \end{gather*}" seems to make the trouble.

If I remove "\begin{gather*} ...  \end{gather*}" to simply use "$...$", I got a compilation problem and a troublesome output, where the "braces" are making troubles in the wrong position:

[image]

> PS. My last figure is what I am hoping to get (with tunable size, like 2/3 or 3/4 of the whole document width). But it shall also be scale-invariant as the same smaller one as the one in my first figure. The code should be also compilable.
>
> Edit 1: This seems to cause the trouble `\\[-\normalbaselineskip]`, which outputs "LaTeX Error: There's no line here to end."

My following attempt can not be compiled fully:

```
\documentclass[aps,prl,twocolumn,superscriptaddress,floatfix,letterpaper,nofootinbib]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb,varwidth}
\usepackage{showframe}


\begin{document}


\onecolumngrid
\begin{widetext}

\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering
\begin{center}
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{%
  \begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}
$
\overbrace{\underbrace{A \times B}_E\times
               \underbrace{C\times {D}}_{EFG}}^{\text{ABCDEFG}}\\[-\normalbaselineskip]
    \underbrace{\hphantom{A\times B\times C\times D}}_{\text{family}}
$  \end{varwidth}}
 \end{center}
  \caption{}
\end{figure}
\end{widetext}
\twocolumngrid

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you make a mock-up of what you're after? All you talk about are problems without a clear instruction of the expected output. Also, there is no `\onecolumngrid` or `\twocolumngrid`.

Comment: Thank you Werner, what I am after is similar to the "last figure." (But I did not get a error-free compilation for that figure. Also the figure is not scale invariant from the original smaller one)

Comment: There "are" \onecolumngrid and \twocolumngrid in my template

Comment: @Werner, I am still in trouble to make it work --- any enlightenment will count as an answer to me.

Comment: It seems that my compilation error 

"LaTeX Error: There's no line here to end."

is due to something from here "\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}  \begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}"

Comment: Edit 1: This seems to cause the trouble \\[-\normalbaselineskip]

Comment: @Werner, maybe the OP question can be resolved by drawing a "transparent line" after  \\[-\normalbaselineskip] ? Yes?

Answer (score 2):

Since displayed math uses the entire width of the column, varwidth won't help.  Instead you need to measure the width seperately and use a normal minipage.

Note the the actual width of the underbrace is slightly larger than its measured width.  One gets the same result using `\sbox0{$\displaystyle A\times B\times C\times D$}%`.

```
\documentclass[aps,prl,twocolumn,superscriptaddress,floatfix,letterpaper,nofootinbib]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb,varwidth}
\usepackage{showframe}


\begin{document}


\onecolumngrid
\begin{widetext}

\begin{figure}[htp]% I have yet to find a case where ! makes any difference whatsoever
\centering
\sbox0{$\displaystyle \underbrace{\hphantom{A\times B\times C\times D}}_\text{family}$}% measure width
\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{\begin{minipage}{\wd0}
  \begin{gather*}
    \overbrace{\underbrace{A \times B}_E\times
               \underbrace{C\times {D}}_{EFG}}^{\text{ABCDEFG}}\\[-\normalbaselineskip]
    \underbrace{\hphantom{A\times B\times C\times D}}_{\text{family}}
  \end{gather*}
  \end{minipage}}
  \caption{}
\end{figure}
\end{widetext}
\twocolumngrid

\end{document}
```